# Unresolved external symbol in MIDL COM library

Tags: c++, interface, com

My system is a Windows 10 64-bit fall creators edition with Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

I have a COM interface with the following IDL (ISomeInterface.idl):

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(61E246F6-3F22-404B-8EA8-E4D13F3206D6),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ISomeInterface : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT DoSomething();
}

[
    uuid(7EF22D33-5C29-4D32-BFBC-0B276C5F7427),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("ISomeInterface 1.0 Type Library")
]
library ISomeInterfaceLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(BC91D238-B0E1-4FA2-AAC8-195D761DF9DC),
        version(1.0),
        helpstring("ISomeInterface Class")
    ]
    coclass ISomeInterfaceImpl
    {
        [default] interface ISomeInterface;
    };
};
```

Which I compile with this command:

```
midl /iid "ISomeInterface_i.c" /env win32 /h "ISomeInterface.h" /W1 /char signed /tlb "Release\ISomeInterface.tlb" /Oicf /D "NDEBUG" /robust /nologo /proxy "ISomeInterface_p.c" ISomeInterface.idl
```

Then I create a module definition file (ISomeInterface.def):

```
LIBRARY     "ISomeInterface"

EXPORTS
    DllGetClassObject       PRIVATE
    DllCanUnloadNow         PRIVATE
    DllRegisterServer       PRIVATE
    DllUnregisterServer     PRIVATE
    IID_ISomeInterface      DATA
    LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib DATA
```

And I build my interface DLL using these commands:

```
cl /c /Zi /W1 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D REGISTER_PROXY_DLL /D NDEBUG /D _WINDLL /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:prompt dlldata.c ISomeInterface_i.c ISomeInterface_p.c

link "/OUT:Release\ISomeInterface.dll" rpcns4.lib rpcrt4.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib "/DEF:ISomeInterface.def" /MANIFEST "/ManifestFile:Release\ISomeInterface.dll.intermediate.manifest" "/MANIFESTUAC:level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" "/PDB:Release\ISomeInterface.pdb" /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT "/IMPLIB:Release\ISomeInterface.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /DLL Release\dlldata.obj Release\ISomeInterface_i.obj Release\ISomeInterface_p.obj
```

My issue is that when I create my ATL executable it keeps failing to link giving me this:

```
SomeApp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib
```

I am using `#include "ISomeInterface.h"` and have added `ISomeInterface.lib` to Linker->Input.

Running `dumpbin.exe /exports Release\ISomeInterface.dll` provides the following:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Release\ISomeInterface.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for ISomeInterface.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    5ABD61A2 time date stamp Thu Mar 29 17:58:58 2018
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           6 number of functions
           6 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001040 DllCanUnloadNow
          2    1 00001000 DllGetClassObject
          3    2 000010A0 DllRegisterServer
          4    3 000010E0 DllUnregisterServer
          5    4 000030E8 IID_ISomeInterface
          6    5 000030F8 LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib

  Summary

        1000 .data
        1000 .orpc
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text
```

Running `dumpbin.exe -headers Release\ISomeInterface.lib | findstr /c:"  Symbol name  :"` shows that the symbol in in the LIB file:

```
  Symbol name  : _IID_ISomeInterface
  Symbol name  : _LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib
```

If I use the `ISomeInterface_i.c` in the project and remove the LIB then it compiles fine, but I am attempting to get away from that...

Comment: You are trying way too hard to hammer your mental model of how DLLs should work.  Any client of your COM server will never ever link to your import library, so exposing it is pointless.  Not how COM works, they'll use your factory function (DllGetClassObject), it is the COM plumbing built into the OS that finds it.  Happens at runtime, never at link time.  Standard vehicles to relay the guid is the `__uuidof` operator and the type library you get from the `library` statement.

Comment: The COM DLL is our defined interface used by multiple servers & clients at the same time. Currently everyone who uses it has to include the *_i.c file generated by the MIDL compiler in order to link their project. I was hoping to get around that by just referencing the import library generated by the COM DLL project because I would think it would already be there. The ATL implementation service uses `DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib)` statements and calls like `GetRecordInfoFromGuids(LIBID_ISomeInterface, 1, 0, 0x409, __uuidof(SomeStruct), &pRI)`. If it just doesn't work that way then ok.

Comment: I would recommend just using `#import` to generate the client code directly from your .dll (or .tlb). The *_i.c file is really for the COM server itself, not its clients.

Comment: Hans is telling you that you don't need to export  IID_ISomeInterface or LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib. These are just constants - the user gets them from the header file or the registry depending.

Comment: Generate a typelib, anyone who wants to use your objects should use `#import`

Comment: I started using the TLB files, but was having a number of issues importing them in a way that didn't require massive code updates (we have several hundreds of projects using these things). They do contain the constants, but the header generated by the MIDL tool does not (only declaration). It was far simpler for me to continue using the header and switch to linking with the LIB rather than compiling the *_i.c files with each project.

Answer (score 0):

So if I delete DATA from the module definition file the symbols link correctly it seems. new file:

```
LIBRARY     "ISomeInterface"

EXPORTS
    DllGetClassObject       PRIVATE
    DllCanUnloadNow         PRIVATE
    DllRegisterServer       PRIVATE
    DllUnregisterServer     PRIVATE
    IID_ISomeInterface
    LIBID_ISomeInterfaceLib
```